# How can I obtain a SIP peer list using pyst?

Tags: python, asterisk, pyst

I would like to show Asterisk SIP peers in my Python application.

I can see such list executing:

```
[pbx:~] # asterisk -rx "sip show peers"
Name/username    Host              Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status      Description
212              (Unspecified)      D  No         No             0        UNKNOWN
213              (Unspecified)      D  No         No             0        UNKNOWN
217/217          169.0.5.17         D  No         No             5060     OK (29 ms)
....
```

In Python I use `pyst 0.8` library:

```py
import asterisk.manager
...
manager = asterisk.manager.Manager()
try:
    manager.connect(host, port)
    manager.login(usr, passwd)
    r = manager.sippeers()

    print('------- r ----')
    pp.pprint(r)
    print('-----------')
    # ...
```

Then I pretty print some fields of the response. But all I get is:

```
------- r ----
Success
-----------
------ response -----
[   u'Response: Success\r\n',
    u'ActionID: pbx-25332-00000001\r\n',
    u'EventList: start\r\n',
    u'Message: Peer status list will follow\r\n']
-----------
------ data -----
u''
-----------
------ headers -----
{   u'ActionID': u'pbx-25332-00000001',
    u'EventList': u'start',
    u'Message': u'Peer status list will follow',
    u'Response': u'Success'}
-----------
----- multiheaders ------
{   u'ActionID': [u'pbx-25332-00000001'],
    u'EventList': [u'start'],
    u'Message': [u'Peer status list will follow'],
    u'Response': [u'Success']}
-----------
```

How can I obtain list of SIP peers using `pyst`?

Asterisk version:

```
asterisk -r -vvvvv
Asterisk 11.17.1, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2013 Digium, Inc. and others. ...
```

Comment: at this moment there are no working python binding for modern AMI. Response for command action will be like this: https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-example-command/

Comment: Best option is use ARI instead: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Endpoints+REST+API

Comment: It is a old version of Asterisk: asterisk -r -vvvvv
Asterisk 11.17.1, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2013 Digium, Inc. and others.
Created by Mark Spencer <markster@digium.com>

Comment: I think ari was in 11. But I highly not  recommend you use asterisk 11, becuase it EOL at 2017-10-25. There is no much config diff in moving to 13, so use 13 LTS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sippeers()` is just a shortcut for sending [the `SIPpeers` command](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_SIPpeers) directly. It doesn't do any listening for resulting events. According to documentation you get `Peerlist` and `PeerlistComplete` events after sending the command, so you will need to register a listener for the events. I haven't worked with pyst, so I'm not familiar with [the structure of the events](https://pyst2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/asterisk/manager.html#Event), but hopefully this helps.

```py
import asterisk.manager
...

def evt_handler(evt, mgr):
    print(f'Got event {evt.name}')
    # do something with evt.data or evt.message

    if evt.name == 'PeerlistComplete':
        mgr.close()
    
manager = manager.Manager()
try:
    manager.connect(host, port)
    manager.login(usr, passwd)
    manager.register_event('Peerlist', evt_handler)
    manager.register_event('PeerlistComplete', evt_handler)
    manager.sippeers()
```

Comment: OK. My manager receives `PeerEntry` event with `headers` containing data that I'm interested in. Thank you :-)

Comment: So I had to use `PeerEntry` instead of `Peerlist` in your solution.